# Is appending the html faster than pasting it multiple times?

Tags: jquery, html

Say that I have a `<div class="statistics"></div>` that I need placed in 5 different places in a single HTML page. That *statistics* `div` has a 6 row long list.

My question is this..

Is it faster to use:

```
<div class="statistics"></div>
```

and then use jquery like this:

```
$( ".statistics" ).append( $(<ul><li>content</li><li>content</li><li>content</li><li>content</li><li>content</li><li>content</li></ul>'));
```

...rather than *copy/paste* the code in those 5 different places ?

Comment: If you copy/paste the code in those 5 different places, it may be slower for you but faster while rendering your document (which I think it matters)

Comment: In addition I would say that depends on how the html markup is created in the first place. If copied manually, then the comment above is true and final. Otherwise it depends... Also, when getting picky, the network speed and latency might be relevant... And many other factors too, once you start thinking about the question :-) So no clear answer is possible, I'd say.

Comment: @JFK So, 5 times more code in the HTML is faster to render than half that amount of code appended with jquery?...

Comment: @Alin : I would say yes, javascript DOM manipulation is slower than pure HTML in most cases ..... and jQuery is slow ;)

Comment: @arkascha it is/will be copied manually, but could you please elaborate what you mean by "it depends".

Comment: Didn't I elaborate enough? Ah, you mean when _not_ typed in manually. Well then the process generating the html markup probably will take longer, since it has more output to produce and to send. The problem with such questions is that you cannot really make any statements about the environment. Too many variables. For example: what client? on what system? Under what load? Same for the server side...

Comment: @arkascha For what I needed, yes, but I only wanted to know in which case it depends and on what :)

Comment: @JFK Ok, I got it, not a good practice of jQuery :) Thanks and have a great day.

Comment: Note one general aspect though: software is never final, it has to be maintained. That means the code has to be understood later on. This is why it absolutely makes sense to code as transparent as possible. You jQuery approach looks more like trying to hide the final markup layout :-)

Comment: @arkascha Thank you and have a great day. You and JFK satisfied my curiosity and prevented a mistake from happening :)

Comment: You're better off use pure JavaScript with `document.createElement` which is faster and using `appendChild` natively its faster by 1,000,000 processes than using a library.

Comment: @arkascha We both know that's no way of hiding the final markup layout :) Anyway, that was not my intention, I just didn't want to transform the html docs in php to include those but I also have more than one of these repetitive divs, therefore I needed to know if appending is a good approach.

Comment: Not talking about the _outcome_ of the final markup. but about the code that creates that markup. Imagine you yourself have to understand your own code say 10 years from now. Believe me: every programmer had situations where he thought about tarring himself when stumbling about such treasures much later...

Comment: @arkascha I see, Ok, you got me convinced. I don't want to end up in that situation. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want faster and efficient with use of jQuery we can use it with native js

```
$('.statistics').each(function(i) {
    var newDOM = document.createElement('ul');
    newDOM.innerHTML = '<li>content</li><li>content</li><li>content</li><li>content</li><li>content</li><li>content</li>';

    this[i].appendChild(newDOM);
});
```

Comment: So, while using the jQuery library with native js it will make my code a lot faster it will not as fast as if I were to turn my document into php and include the code...Right?

Comment: No if you use php that is the correct way. hard code is better than dynamic code.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is always going to be the same then, or when it's updated it will need to be updated the same in all five places then appending the div via jQuery would be a quicker option and provide one maintainable place.

Though you would probably want to change your script to

```
$(".statistics").each(function(){
   $(this).append("<ul> ... </ul>");
});
```

In order to append to each `div`. There's better alternatives to this like using a template engine or even php to include a HTML file which would have the six rows in it.

Comment: Although I would advise against using jQuery just to save coding time, I agree PHP would be an alternative way to render HTML code faster than copy/paste (but I am not too sure it applies on the context of the OP)

Comment: While I also agree that using php is a good way of doing this, I also have to agree with @JFK, this isn't quite what I needed since I wanted to know if it's a good practice of jquery append. And, as it prove out it isn't...Thanks